# SQL Server 2005 IIS connection to Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, iis

I am trying to get SQL Server 2005 (64 bit) SSIS to connect to an Oracle 10 G database. I am able to connect to the database using SQL developer (an Oracle product) from the same server but my attempts from IIS are not working. Any help or links to help will be appreciated. I keep getting errors about Oracle client and networking components were not found. I have already installed ODAC10203x64.  Thanks you for any assistance.

Comment: How are you connecting?  Is the app pool running as 64 bit?  What error are you getting?  Specifics usually help.

Comment: This is on a Windows 2003 64 bit server. On of the errors I am getting is: The OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Then it sounds like you don't have the correct database drivers installed.  You need to make sure you install the OLE DB drivers for the Oracle client for the version of the application you are using (32 or 64 bit).